# jquery-ui resizing one element effects others

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-ui

I have one toolbar which has draggable 3 images and one page field that you can drop that images into. I am planning to drag-drop unlimited item from toolbar to page field and resize them as i wish. Dragged elements are acting strange(jump anywhere or disappear somehow), if i drag-drop 3 or more item from "toolbar" to "page field" and try to resize them.

You can check-out here:
http://jsfiddle.net/v3W62/

```
$(function () {
                $(".toolbar li").draggable({
                    helper: "clone",
                    revert: "invalid",
                    grid: [20, 20]
                });
                $(".page").droppable({
                    accept: ".toolbar li",
                    drop: function (event, ui) {
                        $("<div style='background:black; position:absolute'><img></img></div>").draggable({ 
                            cursor: "move", grid: [20, 20], containment: "parent" 
                        }).resizable({
                            containment: "parent", handles: "n, w, e, s, es", grid: 20      
                        }).height(100).width(100).appendTo(".page");
                    }
                })
            });
```

For example:
1-Try to add one image into yellow page.
2-Drag that image bottom of the yellow page.
3-Try to re-size that image.

Comment: It seems to work fine. They don't disappear, they just go on top of another.

Comment: Yeah, seems to work for me too. But if it are real images maybe you should pass the aspect ratio via php to javascript and then use resizables aspectRatio and as handles just: 'se, es'.

Comment: For example: 1-Try to add one image into yellow page.  2-Drag that image bottom of the yellow page. 3-Try to resize that image.

Comment: Did my fix help by the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah ok, now I see. I deleted the containment option and added a maxWidth and maxHeight option instead:

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v3W62/1/

Here the changed lines:

```
//containment: "parent", 
maxHeight: $('.ui-droppable').height(),
maxWidth: $('.ui-droppable').width(),
```

Seems to work. Please try it and let me know if it helped :)

Comment: Thx. It is working. Do you know, Why containment option cause this problem?